# Add "this" to a vector on class instantiation in C++

Tags: c++, class

I'm coming from a Python background, so forgive me on this one.  Though I will provide the Python equivalent of what I'm looking for.

I'm creating a list of network nodes, so I wanted to create a class, "Node", that stores their MAC, IP address, and Hostnames, along with a function that prints them out prettily.  The following is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Node {
    string MAC, IP, Hostname;
    public:
        void set_values(string M, string I, string H);
        string list() {return "MAC: "+MAC+"\nIP: "+IP+"\nHostname: "+Hostname+"\n";}
};

void Node::set_values(string M, string I, string H) {
    MAC = M;    
    IP = I;     
    Hostname = H;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Node firstnode;
    firstnode.set_values("C0:FF:EE:C0:FF:EE","192.168.1.60","My-PC");
    cout<<firstnode.list();
}
```

Which prints this out when I run it:

```
MAC: C0:FF:EE:C0:FF:EE
IP: 192.168.1.60
Hostname: My-PC
```

What I want is to have these objects automatically added to a vector called NodeList upon creation.  For example, here is how I did that in Python:

```
RecordersList=[]
class Recorder:
    def __init__(self, ARecorder, BRecorder, CRecorder):
        self.ARecorder = ARecorder
        self.BRecorder = BRecorder
        self.CRecorder = CRecorder
        RecordersList.append(self)
```

I tried a similar move, where I put the line:
`vector<Node> NodeList;` before the class declaration (and `NodeList.push_back(this);` as a Public function), and tried after the class declaration, but either way the compiler isn't aware of the Node class by the time the vector is declared, or vice versa the Node class isn't aware of the NodeList vector.

Is there a way to do this?  It would be self-referencial class appending to an existing vector whose type is of that class.

Comment: This is really a bad idea from a design point of view.

Comment: Why?  I'm new(er) to C++, please explain.

Comment: For starters you are creating a type that is bound to be used with a single container, which means that you will not be able to define multiple networks in the same program. There are other issues (like `list()` instead of the idiomatic `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&,Node const&)`), the extra copies of the strings that are done in your interface (`set_values(std::string,std::string,std::string)`), the two phase construction (does it make sense to have a `Node` with no IP?

Comment: It can be very helpful to have a global list of every object of a given type that has been instantiated.  I've used this pattern to check for double deletes for debugging purposes.  It's also useful if you construct the object in multiple places, but don't want to pass a container around.

Comment: Yes, it does make sense to have a Node without an IP or Hostname.  I start out by interrogating my Cisco switches for MAC addresses.  Then I use a database holding our PC's MAC addresses --> hostnames, then use nslookup to get IP addresses by Hostname.  In each step in between these objects may hold empty values.  And I'm only dealing with this one network for this program.

Comment: This is actually hard to maintain code, and as you say it is a direct copy paste technique from python to c++. In c++ I would recomend maintaining vector collection outside Node class (ie. in your main function), and storing instances in this vector just after creating Node instances, or maybe create another class called NodeManager that will manage Node instances by storing them in collection. In c++ nothing protects you from shooting yourself in the foot, and your code looks exactly like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, this sort of design will often not end well due to having to manually manage memory in C++. `this` is a raw pointer to the object and it is not managed.

You can do this:

```
class Node; // forward declaration
std::vector<Node*> NodeList;

class Node
{
public:

    Node()
    {
        NodeList.push_back(this); // pass a POINTER to this object
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Node* node1 = new Node(); // allocated a Node
    Node* node2 = new Node(); // allocated a Node

    // ...

    // deallocate ALL nodes
    std::vector<Node*>::iterator it = NodeList.begin();
    while (it != NodeList.end())
    {
        delete *it;
        ++it;
    }

    NodeList.clear();
}
```

The problem with this solution is if you have pointers pointing to indivual nodes. You could end up with dangling pointers and memory corruption.

And alternative solution is:

```
class Node
{
public:

    Node();
};

std::vector<Node> NodeList;

Node::Node()
{
    NodeList.push_back(*this); // pass a REFERENCE to this object
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Node node1; // create a node
    Node node2; // create a node

    // ...
}
```

The problem with this alternative design is that each node passed to `NodeList` will be a new COPY of that node. So if you do:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Node node1; // NodeList[0] is logically equal to node1

    node1.DoStuffThatModifiesTheContent();

    // At this point, node1 is no longer a logical equivalent of NodeList[0]
}
```

A better design would involve creating a **NodeManager** class of some sort, and creating and accessing nodes through this manager, which would control the lifetime of all the node objects.

Answer (score 3):

Sure: declare and define a static member in the class, push the `this` pointer onto it:

```
class Foo; // forward declaration to make vector happy

class Foo {
    private:
        static std::vector<Foo *> store;
    public:
        Foo() { store.push_back(this); }
};

std::vector<Foo *> Foo::store;
```

Answer (score 2):

Do it explicitly:

```
   std::map<std::string, Node> map;
   map[mac1] = Node(mac1,...);
   map[mac2] = Node(mac2,...);
```